# BMS BQ25731 modelling using datasheet

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit, simulation, modelling

How Can I design model for BQ25731 BMS using Datasheet? What procedure I need to follow Or what should I look for in a datasheet? Any suggestion or any Application note you recommend.

I'm asking this because I have never made a model of any IC before. So, it's a new experience for me. And I need help in this regard.

Thanks,

Comment: This appears to be a near-duplicate of your previous question: [Couldn't find SPICE model of BMS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610575/couldnt-find-spice-model-of-bms) - have you tried TI forums?

Comment: For anyone interested in this topic, and following from the comment above, the OP has now [asked this question on the TI forums](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/1081958/bq25731-model-of-the-bms-ic-required). Therefore new information / updates might be seen there.